# unresolved reference MergeAdapter

Tags: android, android-mergeadapter

I was using `MergeAdapter` in my code . Every thing worked fine until I updated my `RecyclerView` version to `1.2.0-alpha04` . Now my code shows unresolved reference `MergeAdapter`

```
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha04"
```

Answer (score 4):

MergeAdapter has been renamed to ConcatAdapter in `1.2.0-alpha04` release, so refactor your code and change `MergeAdapter` to `ConcatAdapter`

You can see the discussion over here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158019211

> MergeAdapter has been renamed to ConcatAdapter to avoid any confusion with different data merging behaviors

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview#recyclerview-1.2.0-alpha04